# При долгом определении местоположения получаю ошибку

Tags: android

Я создаю приложение в Android Studio.

Мне нужно, чтобы приложение при открытии мгновенно показывало мое местоположение [на гугл картах?] и зум был 17f.

У меня работает, но когда местоположения долго определяется, то приложение выбрасывает ошибку. Это бывает, когда я перезагрузил телефон или только что включил геолокацию на телефоне. Помогите мне.

```
location2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
latLng3 = new LatLng(location2.getLatitude(),location2.getLongitude());
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng3, 17f));
```

Answer (score 2):

Дополните вопрос. Чем вы пользуетесь, Гуглкарты? Какая ошибка вылетает?

Прибегнув ко своим небольшим экстрасенсорным способностям предположу, что когда вы только включили геолокацию/телефон система еще не получила текущего положения, и когда вы его запрашиваете получаете null. А когда преобразовываете его в LatLng вылетает NullPointerExeption.

Вариант избежать этой ошибки примерно следующий:

```
//получаем Handler, который позволяет создавать задачи в основном потоке
final Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper())

//кладем в handler наш Runnable, который 
handler.post(
    new Runnable(){
        //получаем 
        location2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        //если получили null, то вызываем этот же Runnable, но через 100 милисекунд
        if(location2 = null)
            handler.postDelayed(Runnable.this, 100L) 
        else {
            //если не нулл - передвигаем карту
            latLng3 = new 
            LatLng(location2.getLatitude(),location2.getLongitude());
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng3, 17f));
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: дорогой Дмитрий я не русский и поэтому у меня проблемы с грамматикой извините если это вас оскорбила , да вы правы у меня такая проблема я использую гугл карту а как мне исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Никаких проблем, просто скажите об этом в вопросе в следующий раз. Здесь люди весьма дружелюбны и отредактируют ваш вопрос, если потребуется. Для того чтобы решить проблему нужно ее определить. Пока мы только знаем, что она есть. Я сделал предположение про nullPointerException, нужно его проверить. Воспроизведите ошибку во время отладки и посмотрите содержимое Logcat

Comment: а, прошу прощения, невнимательно прочитал ваш комментарий и не до конца понял. Измените код так, чтобы если lm.getLastKnownLocation вернул null система попробовала запросить снова. Чтобы сказать как именно это сделать нужно больше вашего кода в примере, вы можете его добавить отредактировав вопрос

Comment: Дмитрий  я все понял ,помогите написать код чтобы система попробовала запросить снова

Comment: только ту часть запроса

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: дорогой Дмитрий у меня еще один вопрос ,как в приложение добавить чтобы при открывание приложения показать окно запроса включить локацию или нет , разрешение включить локацию телефона

Comment: Создайте отдельный вопрос, я там отвечу. Здесь не принято в одной теме 2 вопроса обсуждать

Comment: Уже создал дорогой Дмитрий